# JQuery 1.3.1 doesn't find dynamically generated rows

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic

I have just installed in the ASP.NET MVC RC2 and with that also using the JQuery 1.3.1 library.
Before I was using the 1.2.6 library. 
Our application works fine under that library.
But now I have strange problem.
We have a grid view that we build up with the result of an AJAX call.
With the result returned we add new rows to a table through cloning a hidden row.

The generated HTML from the JQuery is placing extra parameters to the tags.
These are in the form of JQuery12345678="null".
They all have the same name.
In the head of the table there is a checkbox that selects/unselects all the rows of the table.
This by iterating through the rows of the table.

```
$("#selectAllCheckbox").click(function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $("#dgNewTasks tbody tr").find(':input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        this.checked = checked;
    });
});
```

Now by using the new library the check box are no longer set.
I have used IE Developer Tools to check the HTML.
If I remove the JQuery12345678="null" parameter from my rows. It works fine.

Could someone tell me what I have to do?

Comment: Can you please give an example of the relevant html snippet? Mozilla Firefox provides a JavaScript error console, please have a look if there are any errors/exceptions by firing the event.

Answer (score 1):

We need to see your HTML.  That might illuminate the problem.  In the meantime, your code can be greatly simplified:

```
$("#selectAllCheckbox").click(function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $("#dgNewTasks tbody tr :checkbox").attr("checked", checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this does not work because you attach the event handler (for example `click()`) in the `ready()` event handler and at this moment there is no any dynamically created rows. so, attach the `click()` or any other event handlers to the dynamically created rows after they have been created.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of .click:

```
$("#selectAllCheckbox").live(function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $("#dgNewTasks tbody tr").find(':input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        this.checked = checked;
    });
});
```